# how to animate for unlimited time?

Tags: jquery

I have applied the following jquery:

```
$('.prev').on('mouseenter', function(){
        var $b = $('#banner img').parent('div');
        $b.animate({left: '-=100px'},1000);
    });
```

But this will animate upto 1 second like this if I add 50000 then it will animate upto 50 seconds but I want to animate for unlimited time. How can I do that?

---

Oooops! my concept was a little mistake. When we define the speed this will animate the object taking time 1 seconds or say 50 seconds but in my case when over to `.prev` the object `$b`  should be animated with `-=` concept.

Comment: How can something animate in a single direction for an unlimited time? There is only a finite amount it can move.

Comment: To show animation you need speed, which is a function of time and distance, so when the time of your animation approaches infinity, the speed will approach zero, right?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It's possible, not just in this instance. Think of a simply `cos`/`sin` algorithm that moves a shape in a circle. Unlimited time.

Comment: @h2ooooooo fair point, however this example is linear movement. I updated my original comment :)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Hence the *not just in this instance* which I just realized was "just woke up" for *just not in this instance*. :-)

Comment: Depending on the real use case: Wouldn't also an infinite CSS animation be a better and less computive solution?

Comment: @insertusernamehere It depends a lot on your target audience. CSS animation is AFAIC part of the CSS3 spec, and not all people have CSS3 browsers.

Comment: @h2ooooooo True that. :)

Comment: you guys are getting away from the topic, @C-Link I think You need to explain better what you are trying to do exactly, because in your case, I imagine that after a few seconds the banner would just disappear, so it's confusing.

Comment: @h2ooooooo this is linear movement but won't be ended ever coz after an end append behaviour is triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> this is linear movement but won't be ended ever coz after an end
>   append behaviour is triggered

So, in other words, you don't want to make the animation slower (like going from 1s to 50s does), but animate it at constant speed, in one direction, right?

Then re-initialize the animation in a callback function triggered after the animation:

```
var animate = function(){ 
        var $b = $('#banner img').parent('div');
        $b.stop().animate({left: '-=100px'},1000, 'linear', animate);
}
$('.prev').on('mouseenter', animate);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KH4vS/

[Edit in response to comment]

To stop the animation on mouseleave use

```
$('.prev')
.on('mouseenter', animate)
.on('mouseleave', function(){ $('#banner img').parent('div').stop(); });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KH4vS/1/

Comment: Oh! yeah, I was searching exactly as yours. Thanks.

Comment: but I want to remove that animate after mouseleave....

Comment: @C-Link edited my answer to reflect on that.

Answer (score 0):

A possible way is defining an [animations](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_animations.asp) on CSS rules, and with jQuery event, add to the item you want a class.

In the animation's definition, use

```
animation-iteration-count: infinite
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a css3 keyframe animation.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/hQQSd/

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    from{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

#rotate {
    width:256px;
    height:256px;
    -webkit-animation: rotate 3s linear infinite;
}
```

here you can find out more about the syntax: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/